# Target element from another component onClick - React JS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a toggle icon in my header.js component that on click I want to change the class of an element in my sidebar component in order to change its width and minimize it to half its width. What is the best way I can do this with react? I have a toggleSidebar function on my header component that checks for its state and changes it onclick, but im not sure where to go from here?

header.js :

```
import React from "react";

export class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggleSidebar = this.toggleSidebar.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isToggled: false
        }
    }

    toggleSidebar() {
        if(this.state.isToggled) {
            this.setState({
                isToggled: false
            })

        } else {
            this.setState({
                isToggled: true
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#" onClick={this.toggleSidebar}><span className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item active">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#"><img alt="User DP" className="header__user__img img-fluid rounded-circle" src="../resources/img/user.jpg" /> Mark Hughes</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

sidebar.js :

```
import React from "react";

import SidebarCategories from "./SidebarCategories";

export class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar col-sm-2">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="sidebar__header col">
                        <img alt="Logo" className="img-fluid sidebar__header__logo" src="../resources/img/logo-white.png" />
                        {'\u00A0'} <h4 className="sidebar__header__title i-block">Title</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="sidebar__user container-fluid">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-4 text-center">
                                <img alt="User DP" className="sidebar__user__img img-fluid rounded-circle" src="../resources/img/user.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-8">
                                <p><strong>Welcome</strong><br />
                                Mark Hughes</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <SidebarCategories />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: the simplest solution would be to place the isToggled var outside of your header and pass it down to the header and sidebar component.

Comment: You could either move `isToggled` state up to the common components parent. Or switch to a centralized state management solution (redux, mobx etc)

Comment: BTW if you are using current state it is better to pass a mutation function `toggleSidebar(){this.setState(({ isToggled }) => ({isToggled: !isToggled}))}` Otherwise you might have inconsistent changes on fast repeated calls (keep in mind `setState` is async and batched).

Comment: @YuryTarabanko which of the two would you recommend i look into?

Comment: @MarkHughes88 Me personally prefer redux. But it requires you to learn a couple of new concepts comming from functional programming (immutability, pure functions, side effects). But it really depends on the size of your application, previous background and even personal taste.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko well this app is just something im building to learn react. I want to try and make a basic CMS with a couple of plugins. Ive not worked with frameworks like this before, only ever jQuery

Comment: @MarkHughes88 Google for "redux vs mobx" and choose the one that sounds better to you.